# Finding "max speedup" from a minimum makespan

Tags: algorithm, performance, graph, parallel-processing, minimum-spanning-tree

I have an exam tomorrow in my parallel computing class, and the notes I took on minimum spanning trees are unfortunately lacking. Since I took them at the beginning of the year, I've forgotten what I meant about some of the stuff I wrote, and searching google has left me without answers.

For the exam I will need to understand spanning trees, including (judging from my notes) finding a "critical path" and speed, as well as max speedup. Critical path seems simple enough: it's the weighted path where the length is maximized. My notes on finding this are (where w is weight):

```
D[i] = Length of longest path starting at node i
```

`D[i] = w(i)` if i has no outgoing edges

```
D[i] = max{w(i) + D[j]}

i->j
```

And the steps to finding D are as follows:

1. Find a valid topological ordering
2. Calculate D[i]
3. Find node where D[i] is maximized
4. Backtrack to find critical path

This is simple enough and can often be done with some intuition and arithmetic. There are arrows throughout the graph that indicate valid topological ordering. Here is a small example I drew to give an idea, as most of the images you might find when you search don't have arrows:

[image]

Then to find speed, you take the summed weight of the path divided by the total weight in the entire graph. This is simple enough too. The problem I have is finding the "max speedup."

My notes say that (at least for the graph I was looking at at the time) the max speedup was `1/(5+(1-5)/n`).

I doubt that the "5" is applicable to all graphs. What am I missing here? I think this corresponds to Amdahl's Law, and my guess is that the "5" was the number of nodes, and n is the number of cores running. I'm not sure though, could someone verify/clarify?

Comment: This might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6007289/calculating-the-critical-path-of-a-graph, however i don't get the max-speed up part